# how to create an increment for similar cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this excel 2007 data in column A

```
con
con
con
con
bas
bas
M12
m12
```

I want to create in b and increment for similar cells, so it should look like this:

```
A column B column
con       1
con       2
con       3
con       4
bas       1 
bas       2 
M12       1 
m12       2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response and the efficiency. Very good answer.  I was close but I did not make the range dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the range dynamic.  The first cell in the range is fixed while the second is relative:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

So as it is dragged/copied down the second part of the range will change thus always looking from the cell up.

[image]